# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') Error

Tags: javascript, function

Heyy! I'm trying to do my own modal but it doesn't work correctly.

Here's my code:

```
const modalOpenButton = document.getElementById("modal-open");
const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
const modalCloseButton = document.getElementById("modal-close");

modalOpenButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.style.display = "flex";
});
modalCloseButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  });
```

**EDIT**

Hey guys, I found out how to resolve this problem: I changed the position of the script tag in my HTML file and now it works correctly.

Comment: The error is telling you that `modalOpenButton` and/or `modalCloseButton` is `null`.

Comment: A very common reason for querySelector to return null is that the element is defined below the script, and the script is getting called before the element exists